# Personalization Builder Web Recommendation for Mobile APP

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations

do you know if Marketing Cloud Predictive WEB recommendations works only for  Web ecommerce site or is for an ecommerce Mobile APP too?
I'm wondering if it's able to:
- collect code from ecommerce mobile app
- recommend product on the ecommerce mobile app 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since recommendations are nothing else than an api call to specific endpoint, you can use them wherever you want. Furthermore it is possible to change the recommendations from html to json. Regarding tracking I am not completely sure since I have not worked with the SDK of Salesforce (but since these are nothing else than url calls, where JavaScript has formed the url, i think that this should be easy to implement aswell. )

It’s especially easy if you have a progressive app that is just based on your website and just uses Cordova / phonegap.

Comment: Thanks @[Johannes Schapdick]. I'm wondering if you can send the Contact Id to the Recommendation Json or Html, in the same way you do for email recommendation?

Comment: When you refer to user specific recommendations the answer would be that you can add the "email" parameter to a recommendation call by adding `?email=egiraud@salesforce.com`. When you would track with a unique identifier it will currently disable functionality of predictive web and contact builder although the implementation instruction says `_etmc.push(["setUserInfo", {"email": "INSERT_EMAIL_OR_UNIQUE_ID"}]);` i strongly recommend chosing to place email in there. If you use contact ID for email you must be tracking with contact id in the only shop right?

Comment: If that is the case you probably have to use the email parameter like `?email=contactid` then your personalized home recommendation call of contact 98765 would look like `https://100001234.recs.igodigital.com/a/v2/100001234/home/recommend.json?email=98765`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I am not allowed to comment. But how do you come to the conclusion that it will disable functionality with predictive web and contact builder? Adn what exactly is the functionality you are pointing out here? Thanks

Comment: If you track with unique identifier rather than emailaddress you won't be able to use predictive intelligence data inside journey builder or einstein engagement scoring.

Comment: By saying "currently disable functionality of predictive web" do you Mean the engagement scoring card for conversion?